# Figures' legend is bold. Can I have it not bold in the list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, bold

The legends of my figures are written in bold, but I don't want the list of tables to have the titles in bold. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you using any special packages to format the captions? Adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem would help.

Comment: Please don't edit the title to include `[solved]`. Questions with accepted answers are already marked special. Thanks.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Thanks! I didn't notice that. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [caption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package to customize the captions, not affecting the entries of the corresponding list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
  \caption{a test caption}
  \label{tab:test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gonzalo Medina! Yes it works, exactly what I was searching for. But now another problem comes, now the legend of my figure is: "Figure 1.1::a test caption", but I don't want the colons to show up.

Comment: @Sérgio: you can also change the separator to be used (refer to the package documentation); you can load the package using `\usepackage[font=bf,labelsep=space]{caption}`; a see that you apparently are getting two colons; if some undesired behaviour persists, then you could add a new request to your question, adding a minimal working example.